# How can I record manually using Window's 10 inbuilt screen recording

Tags: windows-10, recording, screen-recorder

I want to use the windows inbuilt recording tool which they provided in Windows 10 for recording my screen. But, not just during the time I play games, also for other purposes as well. But `Win+Alt+R` doesn't seem to work while not playing games. How can I use `Win+Alt+R` to record my screen manually and not use any external tool like (Fraps, CamStudio).

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the directions found [here](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/how-use-windows-10s-screen-recording-utility) it will help you.

1. Locate and run the Xbox App
2. With the Xbox app running launch the app you want to record and press Windows Key + G
3. Tell the Xbox recording app that you want to open the Game bar by telling it the program is a game.
4. Once the Game Bar is loaded choose your action, either Screenshot or Start Recording.

Comment: bud as i mentioned I don't want to use this feature while playing games and stuff. I use `Torch browser` and when I play games on facebook  online. Windows recording automatically pops-up and it records really well. Other than any tool out there in market. So, just  wondering if I can mess around with some Registry and make it as universal recording tool? I don't even use Xbox App

Comment: You can use it just for this. I don't use the Xbox App for playing games, just for recording my desktop.

Comment: try this :- Install `Torch browser`. And once you are in torch just press `win+alt+R` it would start recording your screen. Xbox App not even needed.

Comment: This doesn't work.  Windows + G prompts for it being a game, but the check box won't check.  It just vanishes when clicked on.