# How can I display keystrokes while recording my screen?

Tags: windows-7, screen-recorder, obs-studio

I'm trying to record a video tutorial about using Keyboard Shortcuts. To do this, I want to record my screen while also visually displaying my keyboard inputs.

[image: Displayed keystrokes]

I've been able to find OBS options for "Capture mouse cursor" and "Inverse cursor on click", but I haven't been able to find anything related to displaying keystrokes.

[image: OBS Options]

I've considered using [Windows 10's built-in screen recording](https://superuser.com/questions/956169/how-can-i-record-manually-using-windows-10-inbuilt-screen-recording), but it doesn't seem to have an option for visually displaying keyboard input. (It also isn't available for Windows 7, which is what my main laptop is using.)

**How can I visually display keystrokes while recording my computer screen?**

Comment: I don't think it can be done with OBS alone. But, you could add a third party keypress application that would show the keystrokes on screen. I'm not an expert on this, but I took a look for you and found some useful information: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23244/screen-capture-tool-showing-clicks-and-keypresses